# MRAVOutputContext crash ios 11 beta

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios11, ios-bluetooth

Is it a known issue to be fixed by apple final non-beta ios 11 release?
Where can i find the MRAVOutputContext reference?

From Crashlytics crash report: (Crash reproduces while starting Bluetooth audio, but cannot reproduce it while in debug)

Crashed: com.apple.coremedia.routingcontext.xpc.notifications
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000fa4a1beb8

```
#23. Crashed: com.apple.coremedia.routingcontext.xpc.notifications
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1856f4430 objc_msgSend + 16
1  MediaRemote                    0x191826618 -[MRAVOutputContext _outputDevicesDidChangeNotification:] + 296
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18615e12c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18615d6cc _CFXRegistrationPost + 420
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18615d430 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1861da9f4 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1860943e0 _CFXNotificationPost + 380
7  Foundation                     0x186ab1498 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
8  AVFoundation                   0x18ba5beb4 AVCMNotificationDispatcherCallback + 200
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18615e12c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18615d6cc _CFXRegistrationPost + 420
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18615d430 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1861da9f4 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1860943e0 _CFXNotificationPost + 380
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1860b758c CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 132
15 CoreMedia                      0x1892c6114 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 124
16 CoreMedia                      0x1893c6828 __figXPC_HandleNotificationMessage_block_invoke + 164
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x185b51088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x185b51048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x185b5ae48 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x185b5b7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x185b5c200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x185b644a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185df6fe0 _pthread_wqthread + 932
```

Update: Was fixed in the official release